# Dynamic variable and on click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a few different div's which appear on click of a button - within these div's I am adding text and image.
After I add text or image I want to highlight it when its clicked on but it works only on the default div...

I tried to body, another parent class..
I also hardcoded in other classes which worked?! but obviously, it should not be done this way.
I console.log the variable - and its returning the correct value, yet the on click does not work...

*HTML*

```
<div id="box_side">
    <button value="side_front">FRONT</button>
    <button value="side_back">BACK</button>
    <button value="side_top">TOP</button>
    <button value="side_left">LEFT</button>
    <button value="side_right">RIGHT</button>
</div>
<div id="canvas_side_front" class="canvas front" style="display:none;">
    <!-- Added elements display here -->
</div>
<div id="canvas_side_back" class="canvas" style="display:none;">
    <!-- Added elements display here -->
</div>
<div id="canvas_side_top" class="canvas" style="display:none;">
    <!-- Added elements display here -->
</div>
<div id="canvas_side_left" class="canvas" style="display:none;">
    <!-- Added elements display here -->
</div>
<div id="canvas_side_right" class="canvas" style="display:none;">
    <!-- Added elements display here -->
</div>
```

*jQuery*

```
//This part is not working on any other canvas than canvas_side_front
$('body').on('click', '#' + activeCanvas + ' p.de_select', function() {
    console.log('CANVAS ' + activeCanvas);
});

//default value for activeCanvas
var activeCanvas = 'canvas_side_front';

//part of code to change activeCanvas

$('body').on('click', '#box_side button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.canvas_wrapper .canvas').hide();
    var selected = $(this).val();
    selected_side = $('#canvas_' + selected).attr('id');
    console.log('Selected side: ' + selected_side);
    var calcHeight = 0;
    var canvas = '';

    if (selected_side == 'canvas_side_front') {

        activeCanvas = 'canvas_side_front';
        canvas = $('#' + activeCanvas);

        $('#canvas_' + selected).show();
    } else if (selected_side == 'canvas_side_back') {

        activeCanvas = 'canvas_side_back';
        canvas = $('#' + activeCanvas);

        $('#canvas_' + selected).show();
    }
});
```

I know there is no error here as it works when its hardcoded but maybe I forgot something?

```
$('body').on('click', '#' + activeCanvas + ' p.de_select', function() {
    console.log('CANVAS ' + activeCanvas);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a class to which will make a canvas active i.e. *activeCanvas* and use it with Event Delegation

```
$(document).on('click', '.activeCanvas  p.de_select', function() {
    console.log('CANVAS ' + activeCanvas);
});

$(document).on('click', '#box_side button', function(e) {
    //Rest of your code

    $('.canvas').removeClass('activeCanvas');
    $('#' + activeCanvas).addClass('activeCanvas')
});
```

Comment: @user123456789, As per your code, when event was delegated to `$('body')`  it matches the selector which was supplied when event handler was being attached initially i.e. `#canvas_side_front p.de_select`  it doesn't matter what happens to variable _activeCanvas_ afterwards